# What is the difference between "wood veneer" and "plywood" wood?

Tags: wood

Both wood veneer and plywood both use layers of nautral wood stuck to engineered wood. What is then the difference between them?

Comment: As you know, SE values prior research before asking a Question. What searches did you try and what did you read that didn't clarify you're asking here? You know what plywood is I presume, so all you really need to focus on is veneering (there was already a reference to this in a previous Answer relating to the convention of vertical grain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a bit of foundation to answer upon:

Sheet stock is manufactured flat material consisting of a thicker layer of common wood called a "substrate" and at least one and very often both sides covered by thin layers of fancier wood or plastic called "veneer".

The substrate can be multiple layers of wood turned 90 degrees each layer and glued together. This kind of substrate is called "plywood". Or it can be ground-up wood sawdust with resin glue and called particle board. If the sawdust is ground to very fine dusty particles, then glued with resin, it's called "fiberboard": medium density grinding makes the substrate called MDF.

"Wood veneer" is the outside layer of a piece of sheet stock that is very often a high-quality but thin sheet of wood glued over the substrate. It can be stain-grade oak, cherry, ash, walnut, mahogany, etc. Or it can be paint-grade poplar, birch, etc. Other forms of veneer could be metal, like aluminum, or plastic, like melamine.

So "wood veneer" and "plywood" don't compare: they are two different parts of the sheet stock. "Plywood" is one of the different kinds of middle of the sheet stock. "Wood veneer" is one of the kinds of outside layers of the sheet stock.

Comment: Just one small but important detail: MDF (as well as HDF or hardboard) are not made from wood dust but instead from wood *fibres*.

Comment: Don't forget oriented strand board (OSB) that's made from large flakes of wood pressed & glued together. It's a cross between particle board and plywood. Cheaper than plywood and almost as strong, much more sturdy than particle board. OSB is used heavily in construction, not so much in woodworking.

Answer (score 1):

> Both wood veneer and plywood both use layers of nautral wood stuck to engineered wood. What is then the difference between them?

*veneer* is a thin sheet of material used to cover something, usually for decoration. In a woodworking context, we usually talk about veneer made from wood. Veneers can be cut on a band saw, [sliced paper thin](https://youtu.be/yIk_eZvyefE?t=162) by a very sharp knife, or [peeled from a log](https://youtu.be/GuS5c50cVHs?t=120) on a veneer lathe.

Plywood is an engineered wood product made from a stack of thin sheets of wood, often called plies, which are glued together. The plies are arranged so that the grain in each layer is oriented crosswise to the layer before it, and this gives plywood stability and strength. The outermost layers may be decorative veneers, or not, depending on the intended use of the plywood.

Answer (score 0):

ultimately, the difference comes down to the quality of the outside ply.  both are thin layers of wood stacked and glued together.  Veneered plywood is just very nice wood usually a more expensive one glued on the outside as the last layer. it's a 'cheap' way to make more valuable wood stretch farther.

You can also just buy 'veneer' which is that last layer cut ultra thin, and rolled up.  You can use that to veneer any other wood to make it look better or at least like a more expensive piece.